# JavaFX: check whether a text property is blank (and not just empty)

Tags: javafx, property-binding

I want to have a button enabled or disabled based on whether a text field contains anything, and I want to implement this by using property binding.

So at first I used the isEmpty() method on the text field's text property to create a boolean binding for the button's disabled property:

```
startSearchButton.disableProperty().bind(searchField.textProperty().isEmpty());
```

While the binding works, my definition of "text field contains anything" is different to what the isEmpty() method does, namely just checking if the text's length is > 0. However, I'm interested in whether there is "real" text, i.e. whether the text field is *blank* (not just not empty, but actually not only whitespace).

Unfortunately there is no method isBlank(), and I also couldn't find anything appropriate in the Bindings utility class. Now I saw that you can implement any custom boolean property you like via the Bindings.createBooleanProperty method, but I'm not yet familiar with the concept of defining custom bindings. How would I have to implement such a boolean property for my case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a custom binding using (among many methods) [`Bindings.createBooleanBinding(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createBooleanBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-). The first argument is a function that computes the value of the binding (you can trim whitespace from the text with `trim()` and then check if the result is empty); the remaining arguments are a list of observables that trigger recomputation of the binding. You want to recompute the binding when the text in the text field changes, so just specify the text property:

```
startSearchButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
    searchField.getText().trim().isEmpty(),
    searchField.textProperty());
```

Comment: Ah, your answer gave me even a better understanding of the Observable parameter! Thank you

Comment: oh, just a quick follow-up question please: Is it not required to check if the getText() is null first? Or is it not possible for a (text field's) text property to be null?

Comment: Yes, [`Property`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html) is a subinterface of [`Observable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/Observable.html), so all properties are `Observable`s. I *believe* `getText()` never returns `null`, but there is little harm in adding in a null check.

Answer (score 1):

As for 2022

```java
 public static BooleanBinding isBlank(StringProperty stringProperty) {
        return Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> stringProperty.get().isBlank(), stringProperty);
    }

    public static BooleanBinding isNotBlank(StringProperty stringProperty) {
        return isBlank(stringProperty).not();
    }
```

(idk why didn't nobody suggest `String::isBlank`, perhaps it was added in Java later)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this too:

1. With Apache StringUtils.isBlank()

   ```
   startSearchButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
       StringUtils.isBlank(searchField.getText()),
       searchField.textProperty());
   ```
2. Create you own method

   ```
   public static boolean IsNullOrWhitespace(String s) {
           if(s == null) {
               return true;
           }

           for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
               if(!Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
                   return false;
               }

           }
           return true;
       }
   ```

and then:

```
    startSearchButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
            IsNullOrWhitespace(searchField.getText()),
            searchField.textProperty());
```

Comment: Of course you could do that, you could go even further and define a utility method for the whole thing of setting up such a binding for a given property. But this is irrelevant to the question, which has been already answered by the way. so I don't really know why you are digging out this old question to post this.